# Inconsistent results running external python script from PHP shell_exec

Tags: php, python, command-line, exec, shell-exec

I am having an issue getting a consistent result (sometimes I get the output of the python script, sometimes I don't) using shell_exec(), or exec() within PHP for a python script that **works 100% of the time from the command line**. My guess (unsubstantiated) is that for some reason php is not waiting for a result from the python script prior to closing the process, but i'm not sure.

**Note** I'm using nginx/php5-fpm (not apache)

**Update** I also throw in a sanity check as well which **DOES** work

```
 #sanity.py
 import sys
 sanity = sys.argv[1]
 print "You are totally " + sanity

 echo shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/usr/bin/python sanity.py sane"));
```

I have the following code in PHP that calls a command that runs a python script...

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("/usr/bin/python app.py $var1 $var2")
session_write_close();
shell_exec($command);
```

The python script is (very simplified)

```
import sys

var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2:]

print some_function(var1,var2)
```

Now... when I run this command from the command line as follows...

```
python app.py 1234 asdf
```

I get results without any issues. However, the PHP code only returns a result sometimes (without any real reason as to why only sometimes).

In addition, i've written the following code as an alternate option, and I get similar or the same results... sometimes it works, sometimes it returns nothing...

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("/usr/bin/python /var/app/" . $command);

    $pipes = array();
    $descriptors = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w"),
    );
    session_write_close();
    $process = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes) or die("Can't open process $command!");

    $output = "";
    while (!feof($pipes[2])) {
        $read = array($pipes[2]);
        stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 0);
        if (!empty($read)) {
            $output .= fgets($pipes[2]);
        }
    }

    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    proc_close($process);

    return $output;
```

Is there a way to either troubleshoot what the hell is going on, or solve this so that it works consistently?

Comment: Anything in your apache logs?

Comment: @bassxzero i'm using nginx / php5-fpm but i'll check those logs too

Comment: PHP logs then. What do they say?

Comment: @bassxzero nothing recent or relevant, same with nginx logs

Comment: does the python script do file i/o?

Comment: Have you tried `shell_exec($command . ' 2>&1');`? // Note the leading space character before '2'…

Comment: @bassxzero the script does quite a bit actually... Redis Queries primarily, and does a whole bunch of Gensim work (gensim is why i'm using python in the first place) - Basically the script inputs from command line, gensim work, print result

Comment: @ZoliSzabó tried that yes, no change. Thank you!

Comment: writing in file i/o could be blocking

Comment: Thank you @bassxzero - any suggestions? I'm open to a complete rethink on how I do this... i'd rather not load an external python script (seems like a terrible way to do it, I just don't know another way...)